# How should I set up my security groups so that hackers will not infiltrate so easily

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

So I have an EC2 instance on AWS and it runs Mongodb. I have been having issues with hackers for a few months now and I can't seem to figure out how to keep them out. Luckily, I don't have anything important on there.

I did notice that my security group on AWS is basically open to all. For example, my inbound rules:

Port 80, tcp, 0.0.0.0/0
Port 8080, tcp, 0.0.0.0/0
Port all, tcp, 0.0.0.0/0
Port 22, tcp, 0.0.0.0/0
Port 27017, tcp, 0.0.0.0/0
Port 443, tcp, 0.0.0.0/0

If i change the source is there a convention I should follow? How should I set the source? I am new to this as I did not set up my security groups. Just trying to figure out how I can keep out the hackers. They have been going at it for a while now.

Comment: What of yours needs to access these AWS resources? Use their IP addresses or VPC names.

Comment: So currently I use IP_ADDRESS_A to write to this instance through port 27017. So maybe ill restrict this port and leave http and https range open? Or should I just restrict all the ports to that one address. I do use this instance on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The`0.0.0.0/0` means that the port allows connection from anywhere on the internet.

If you set the source, only the source (whether it's an IP or a range of ups) will be able to access the port.

How are you going to set the source really depends on your needs.

Comment: Hmm Okay. I'll play with a few sources. Would you know the best way I can test a port of my instance?

Comment: Do you know nmap? It's used by hackers too;)

Comment: I see. The only way to stop a hacker is to think like one.

Answer (score 0):

your data source should ideally allow access only from trusted internal IPs. remove full access of all tcp ports. only keep 27017 and map it to the IP address which is accessing your system. For web access, it's best to configure a reverse proxy and access it via that proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only one accessing the EC2 instance, you can edit your security group and choose "My IP" as the Source, and then only you would be able to access it and the hackers will not.

It is best practice to limit command and control ports (22, 3389, etc) to only be accessible from known networks, such as your home, VPN IP pool, or corporate network.